# Unlike other classes, why flash-component classes can't be used without adding them to library?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

A flash component can't be used unless it's added to library. Why this difference as compared to other classes ? Is it only because of the reason that components have "Views" . Or the reason is something else.

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly, how are you attempting to use the components using AS3 and what's failing?  Can you give concrete steps?

Comment: The reason is simple: you have `Classes` and you have `Components`.

Comment: @JevgenijDmitrijev I don't get it based on reading about making a Flash "Component" here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components.html it seems like you're just writing classes to me, only difference I see being you can package as an FLA in the end instead of a SWC which may make a difference in usage, but in the second part of the article he explains they all extend from Sprite.

Comment: @shaunhusain it is simple. class is component and component is class, just the `classes` about which @Vishwas Gagrani talks are the core `classes` from flash. And the `component` is build based on those `classes`, since it is already an external thing, that is the reason you need to add the m to library.

Comment: Is it not because components require graphics of some sort not just drawing api stuff?

Comment: Components are not added to the source path until it is put in the library. Where class files have to be in the path to use them

Comment: Because the fl package relies on graphical assets that only get added to your project when you drag them into the library.  You could in theory create your own substitute classes through code that use the same linkage as the fl. package and make it work without using the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a component to the library, this, behind the scenes, generates the code, or rather an instruction for the compiler to import the classes used in the component.

So, for some components, it would be sufficient to only import them in your AS3 code, given the source code of the component or the SWC with the compiled component is made visible to the compiler by putting it on a "classpath", i.e. the compiler has a list of the directories where it will look for the sources - this is the classpath, placing file into any of these directories makes them available at compile time.

For other components there may be further complications. A component may be imported from another FLA file, where in the original file it was comprised of a compiled part (aka component shim), this usually contains the code that manages the component, and the parts of the component in the format native to Flash IDE, in which they are still editable. This would later allow you to skin the component (as in change some of its visible appearance). So, commonly, these parts are the MovieClips, Sprites, Shapes, or, perhaps sounds etc.

In the second case you usually don't have sources or SWC available to the compiler, so you cannot import it by any other means but placing it in the library.